# php to iphone code - CCHmac kCCHmacAlgSHA256

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restful-authentication, hmac, sha256

I am trying to login to my server using hmac sha256 encryption, i have working code in php, but can't get it working in iphone and traced it to that the hmac in iphone is yielding different output to php code, given same inputs
php code is

```
  $privatekey = '6-y6f"\%BjSM;HBo\'sPr")5#t2nb-LG*;])f^Si[';
  $identity_arrow_getSecret = $privatekey;
  $date_c = "2011-04-18T23:56:28+0800";
  $uri = '/backend/1/User/Header';

  $stringToSign =  "GET\n\n\n" . $date_c . "\n" . $uri;
  $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($stringToSign), $identity_arrow_getSecret);
  echo "stringToSign is $stringToSign <HR>";
  echo "signature is $signature <HR>";
```

objective-c code is

```
NSString* uri = @"/backend/1/User/Header";
NSString* date_c = @"2011-04-18T23:56:28+0800"; //[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString* stringToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\n\n\n%@\n%@" , date_c , uri];
NSLog(@" stringToSign : %@ <>\r\n", stringToSign);

NSString* privatekey = @"6-y6f\"\%BjSM;HBo\'sPr\")5#t2nb-LG*;])f^Si[";

const char *cKey  = [privatekey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [stringToSign cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@" hash : %@ \r\n", hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your Base64 class.  I use the Base64 class written by [Kiichi Takeuchi](http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php) and it gives me identical results to a routine I wrote in C# to verify, so I assume it's correct.

I had to make one small change to your code to verify, as the Base64 library only encodes an NSData structure.  Here's what it looks like:

```
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *nsd = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: cHMAC length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

NSString *hash = [Base64 encode:nsd];
[nsd release];
NSLog(@" hash : %@ \r\n", hash);
```

Comment: i didn't continue with project so i don't know if this helps or not, so don't take it the wrong way if I didn't mark this as correct or not